# Classification of digital orthophoto

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digital-image-processing, land-cover, land-classification

I have digital orthophotographs from 2013 that I'm attempting to classify in an effort to extract all the cultivated/pasture land from.  I'm using the "Reclassify by Ascii File" tool for this procedure.  According to the NLC database values 81-84 are what I'm looking for and this seems to be correct.  The issue I'm running into is that the classification seems to be the opposite of what I need.

My remap file called "remapfile.txt" is as follows:

81 84 : 1

I understand this as extracting pixels with values 81,82,83, and 84 and remapping them to a value of 1.  I check the box to send all other values to NODATA.  However, what is returned seems to be the opposite.  All the areas that have values of 81-84 are mapped as NODATA and all other points are mapped to a value of 1.

Is there a better way to do what I'm doing???

I'm fairly proficient in Python if that helps.

Comment: What raster format is the orthophoto? Is it already classified?

Comment: It is not classified.  It's an 8 bit unsigned image in FGDBR format.

Comment: Your question, then is misleading. You can't "reclassify" a raster that isn't classified to begin with. See the answer below for a suggestion on the initial classification.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I misspoke, only trying to classify.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using an image classification algorithm such as [Maximum Liklihood](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000pp000000) rather than thresholding a single spectral band. This way, you will be able to leverage the information in all of the spectral bands, rather than a single band--thus increasing the accuracy of your classification. If you are working with 4-band NAIP, I would recommend calculating [NDVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Difference_Vegetation_Index) and adding that to your set of raster bands (e.g. Red, Green, Blue, NIR, NDVI) used in the Maximum Likelihood classification.

If you have a particular need for thresholding a single band, you can use the [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) as a tool, in the raster calculator, or within a script. The raster calculator syntax would be something like:

```
Con((InRas1 > 80) & (InRas1 < 85), 1, 0)
```

In other words: If the DN value is between 80 and 85, assign a value of 1, otherwise assign a value of 0.

Comment: I tried using the image classification tool in Arc yesterday but did not get acceptable results.  I created many training polygons and merged them into 6 classes, then created the .gsg signature file.  I ran the Maximum Likelihood tool, which worked but the resolution was very very course around 30-60 meters.The raster I'm using is only 3 bands (RGB) with 0.5 x 0.5 feet cell size. I'm sure I can aquire an image with additional bands but, running NDVI would give me the index for all vegetation in the image right??? For my purposes I only need cultivated land areas. I will try the Con tool.Thanx

Comment: You are going to have problems classifying a 3-band NAIP image. The NIR band is critical to classifying healthy green vegetation. You can try the GRVI (G-R/G+R) instead of NDVI if you do not have the NIR band. Also note that if you are in the US, there is likely 4-band NAIP imagery for your area of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the syntax of this reclassify. You could try to invert it?

> min 80 : 1
>
> 85 max: 1

But, if you're really just after a binary raster, I would give the raster calculator a try.
In QGIS this syntax worked for me:

> "orthophotolayer" >= 81 AND "orthophotolayer" <= 84

This only sets all other pixels to zero. If you need it nodata, you could e.g. vectorize it and SELECT WHERE DN=0 and remove all those polygons you don't need.

Comment: Ok good suggestion.  I'll give the raster calculator a try. Thanks